# ubuntu 19.10 не запускает окно javafx

Tags: java, ubuntu, javafx

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Всем привет столкнулся с таким проблемой ubuntu 19.10 не запускает окно javafx может кто сталкивался заранее спасибо

Comment: может дело в версии java?

Comment: к сожалению нет код запуститься отлично без ошибок просто не отображаеться окно

Comment: А как ты ставил javafx?